Why do certificate CNs not match the hostnames provided in MX records?
I'm the author of checkdmarc, an open source CLI tool for checking DMARC and other email security standards. One of those checks involves testing if the mail servers listed in a domain's MX records supports TLS. I'm finding in many situations the hostnames listed in a domain's MX record do not match the CN or alternative name values of the certificate used by that server. This causes TLS connections to those hosts to fail because of the hostname mismatch.
For example, the MX records for gmail.com are:
gmail.com.              1550    IN      MX      20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1550    IN      MX      40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1550    IN      MX      10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1550    IN      MX      5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.              1550    IN      MX      30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Yet, a quick inspection of the certificate for gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com shows that the CN of the certificate that is offered by that host is mx.google.com. How can I account for this? Are mail clients just ignoring hostname matching on MX servers? That seems nuts!
openssl s_client -connect gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = WR2
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mx.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = mx.google.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = WR2
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jun 24 07:37:53 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 16 07:37:52 2024 GMT
 1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = WR2
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Dec 13 09:00:00 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Feb 20 14:00:00 2029 GMT
 2 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jun 19 00:00:42 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Jan 28 00:00:42 2028 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = mx.google.com
issuer=C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = WR2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5003 bytes and written 441 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)


A certificate may be used for 100 names. It isn't possible to match the CN to all of those names, so there can't be a requirement to match the CN.

"If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead." RFC2818, May 2000. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818.html

Although 2818 only applies to HTTPS; for SMTPS see 6125 appendix B.4 which previously made SAN maybe-should rather than must and 7817 which now fully applies 6125 and makes it must. Also LetsEncrypt limits SAN to 100 entries (which may include wildcards that cover multiple names), and other CAs may have limits and/or charge more, but 5280 doesn't set a limit and I don't think any other standard formally does beyond the fact that TLS can't send a cert or chain exceeding about 16MiB.

Because modern clients verify the domain names listed in the Subject Alternate Name extension instead of the Subject field.
If you look at the certificate you'll see the domain MX names you mentioned:
openssl x509 -noout -text -in google_mx.cer | grep -A1 'Subject Alt'

Returns:
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
    DNS:mx.google.com, DNS:smtp.google.com, DNS:aspmx.l.google.com, DNS:alt1.aspmx.l.google.com, DNS:alt2.aspmx.l.google.com, DNS:alt3.aspmx.l.google.com, DNS:alt4.aspmx.l.google.com, DNS:gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt1.
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt1.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt2.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt3.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:alt4.gmr-smtp-in.l.google.com, DNS:mx1.smtp.goog, DNS:mx2.smtp.goog, DNS:mx3.smtp.goog, DNS:mx4.smtp.goog, DNS:aspmx2.googlemail.com, DNS:aspmx3.googlemail.com, DNS:aspmx4.googlemail.com, DNS:aspmx5.googlemail.com, DNS:gmr-mx.google.com


Thanks. I'm familiar with alt names, I just assumed openssl would list them if they were there. Thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127352/how-to-check-subject-alternative-names-for-a-ssl-tls-certificate
This command will show you a whole pile of SAN entries
openssl s_client  -showcerts -connect gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25 -starttls smtp | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep DNS
